# c# html - hide kendo grid when empty

Tags: c#, html, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have the following Kendo grid in my html code and am trying to hide it if there is no data. I am confused on how to do this since I am using a datasource and not iterating through something to add data.

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<CustomerQuickHistory>()
                  .Name("TransactionDetails")
                  .Columns(cols => {
                      cols.Bound(c => c.DateOfItem).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}");
                      cols.Bound(c => c.ProductName);
                      cols.Bound(c => c.Price);
                  })
                  .DataSource(ds => ds
                      .Ajax()
                      //.Group(g => g.Add(d => d.CustomerName))
                      .Sort(s => s.Add(ad => ad.DateOfItem).Descending())
                      .Read(r => r.Action("TransactionHistory_Read", "Customers", new { customerId = Model.CustomerId }))
                  )
                  )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about using the DataBound event handler to define check the dataSource binded and show or hide the grid.

Here is an example of something similar, but in this case it shows a message when the grid is empty.

http://blog.falafel.com/displaying-message-kendo-ui-grid-empty/

code example:

```html
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.ProductViewModel>()
        .Name("grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(p => p.ProductName).Title("Product Name");
            columns.Bound(p => p.UnitPrice).Title("Unit Price");
            columns.Bound(p => p.UnitsInStock).Title("Units In Stock");
        })
        .Events(events => events.DataBound("onGridDataBound"))
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Read(read => read.Action("Products_Read", "Grid"))
         )
    )

<script>

  function onGridDataBound(e){
    var grid = e.sender;
    
    if (grid.dataSource.total() == 0 ){
    //Hide grid
      $(grid).hide();
    }
    else{
      //Show grid
      $(grid).show();
    }
  }
  
</script>
```

Comment: the grid events are all executed in the browser, but you can register then using c# thought.  
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/events